# Wouldn't this sound kill or seriously maim everyone close to Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In *Man of Steel*, when Clark and General Zod fight! Clark lets out an almighty scream with what seems to be all of his strength.

We know that Superman has a lot of powers that are far more powerful than humans. Below is a quote from the [wiki article](http://dccomicsextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Man_of_Steel_(Novel)) about the Man Of Steel Novel

> Ma and Pa Kent bring a six-month-old Kal/Clark to the doctor. The
>   growing baby couldn't stop crying, and the Kents, trying to find out
>   what was wrong, brought him to get examined. Believing Clark to be
>   suffering from colic, the doctor administers a hearing test, and **Clark
>   proceeds to scream so loud that he blows out the glass elements not
>   just in the doctor's office, but in the windshields and storefront
>   windows across town.** "It was a funny scene but we decided not to keep
>   it in," Goyer said

So we can assume he has this ability in the movie.

Sound is dangerous and kill if loud enough. (see "[Can a loud enough sound kill you?"](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/175996-can-a-loud-enough-sound-kill-you)

> The question is, is 154 decibels enough to kill you? In all honesty,
>   probably not — unless, perhaps, you were stuck with your head inside
>   the horn for a prolonged period. 150 decibels is usually considered
>   enough to burst your eardrums, **but the threshold for death is usually
>   pegged at around 185-200 dB.**

For one, we see Lois on the staircase, at what I would estimate to be about 80ft from Superman.

Using this formula, `SPL = (source SPL)-(20*LOG10(Distance from source))` for measuring diminishing sound over distance, you can calculate that Superman would have to have made a 208 dB scream , which over 80 ft would mean the SPL level would be about 180 dB's @ 80ft.

It is in the realm of possibility that he can make a 208 dB sound, and that making a sound that loud via a scream would in fact kill or maim anyone in close proximity to him.

**Wouldn't this scream have killed or maimed all the people in close proximity to Clark?**

Comment: I don't think it's a spoiler that Superman and Zod fight each other :-)

Comment: @Valorum, I was not sure, so I choose the safe road. Cheers.

Comment: @armadillo, Sorry `LOG10` is an excel function.  Put that formula into excel and it will work. I tested it.

Comment: @KyloRen - You also seem to be referring to a specific scene. Since there's only one person in proximity to Clark, why not just ask the question directly?

Comment: @armadillo, my bad , the scream would have to be 208 db's

Comment: @armadillo, 80ft or 25m.  Yes from the sorce, which would be Superman's mouth/voice box???

Comment: @armadillo, Ok, try this page https://www.easycalculation.com/physics/classical-physics/decibels-distance.php Enter 1 meters from d1 and 26 meters for d2 and it gives a 28db drop in SPL. I am pretty confident my equation is correct. But, if you can point if I am doing something wrong or left something out, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Yes, you put in 1 meter=3 ft, so my random online calculator matches your results. So we’re having Superman stand 3 feet in front of a microphone to measure his epic scream at 208 dB, and another microphone at 80 ft measures 180 dB. I’ll mosey along now.

Comment: @armadillo, Sorry I confused things. Thanks for the check though. Cheers

Comment: Currently humans can't create sounds that are in the 200 dB range without also creating high pressures (which is sort of like sound) and usually fireballs and other destructive forces. For example, right at the launch pad, the launch of a Saturn V rocket was about 220 dB, but you couldn't be that close without suffering injury and likely death from all kinds of other things happening there. So we don't really *know* much about what kinds of sounds (alone) can kill.

Comment: I think humans would be endangered from an *involuntary* Superman scream, but there isn't much that can both hurt Superman enough to make him scream and allow him to retain his powers long enough to emit a super-scream.  If Superman didn't have fine control over his powers, Clark Kent would become human wrecking-ball the first time anyone startled him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Superman was dramatically weakened by his exertions. It seems likely that his super-scream didn't have its normal potency.

From the [novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16113771-man-of-steel)

> His foe had gone the way of Krypton, but Superman wasn’t sure he would ever forgive Zod for making the hero the instrument of his death. Anguish tore at Superman’s heart; he had always sought to save lives, not take them. Killing Zod took a terrible toll on him. **His shoulders slumped as he stood above the body, feeling both emotionally and physically drained**.
>   He really was the Last Son of Krypton now, he realized.
>   Apart and alone.

Comment: Please note that the quote above isn't verbatim. There was a slight typo in the original referring to Zod as "The Zod". I've corrected it.